# In the diffraction of EM waves, what kind of objects do the obstacles need to be?

Tags: electromagnetism, diffraction

In the diffraction phenomenon, when I search for layman examples in youtube, I see an image of an obstacle with a tiny hole (aperture) in it, so that light goes through the aperture and scatter around on the other side.

What kind of object does this obstacle need to be? Does it need to have low electrical resistivity? Can it be a tree or a building made of concrete? (In order for the diffraction to be more significant)

Comment: Something which is opaque to the em waves.

Comment: Yeah but what makes something opaque? Is it the electrical resistivity?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no one factor that says whether a material is opaque. There are a whole lot of factors, which also depend on the wavelength. Resistivity is certainly not the sole answer, as you can easily see by thinking of a couple of examples.

Comment: Which factors and why?

Answer (score 0):

Diffraction can originate from any locus at which sections of a wavefront encounter media presenting a difference in transmittance, reflectance, or refractive index (transmission velocity).

Opacity is not necessary for diffraction. For example, a fine quartz fiber -- however smooth and transparent -- in the path of visible light will considerably diffract that light.

Note that if all sections of a wavefront undergo the same change, diffraction doesn't result.  For example, in principle a wavefront reflecting from a mirror of infinite extent would not be diffracted.

Comment: Hello MarkH, thanks for your response.

Comment: The transmittance, reflectance and refractive index are dependant on the permeability and permitivitty of the medium, because if you know n (refraction index), you can calculate the others, correct? So am I right to conclude that the main electric properties of the material are its permeability and permitivitty to cause the diffraction effect?